# use jQuery console.log value as a php value in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an alert value in jQuery and used that value in a modal in wordpress:

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".varr").click(function() {
        console.log( $(this).attr('data-id'));
        $('#hidden_id').val($(this).attr('data-id'));
    }); 
});
```

I got the alert value in hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_id" name="hidden_id" value=""/>
```

now I want to get the value from hidden field.

Please help how can I get the value from hidden field?

Comment: this is a hidden field in modal:   <input type=”hidden” id=”hidden_id” name=”hidden_id” value="">

Comment: $('#hidden_id').val() is used to retrieve the value..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hidden_id').val()
```

It is used to get the value of your hidden input elements.

Comment: I didnt want to get the id in a form ...i want to the value in modal div as a php variable.

Comment: @varsha the code is not getting id of the input its get the value of hidden input .brief your problem

Comment: i want to store the  "  $(this).attr('data-id') "  the id coming from the attr data  in to the php variable.

Comment: @varsha - whatever the value, you are keeping in it, $('#hidden_id').val()  is used to retrieve the value..

Comment: yes ...i am getting the value in hidden field .....but i am abe to get that value from that field...i want to store the value in a variable.